# add variable in action in a form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to learn HTML and PHP. In an example which i found over the internet i need to set a variable to the submit button. So when the submit button is pressed, this page reloads, with a variable in the address bar,the variable is the one from the drop down menu. like this :

```
test.php?idneeded=$variable
```

in which the $variable is selected by the user and then the page reloads to show specific content related to the chosen option.

For example :

```
test.php?idneeded=40
```

(40 is "MadTechie" from the drop down form)

the code i found is this :

```
<?php
   if( isset($_GET['ajax']) )
   {
      //In this if statement
      switch($_GET['ID'])
      {
         case "LBox2":
            $Data[1] = array(10=>"-Tom", 20=>"Jimmy"); 
            $Data[2] = array(30=>"Bob", 40=>"-MadTechie");
            $Data[3] = array(50=>"-One", 60=>"Two");
         break;

         //Only added values for -Tom, -MadTechie and -One (10,40,50)
         case "LBox3":
            $Data[10] = array(100=>"One 00", 200=>"Two 00");
            $Data[40] = array(300=>"Three 00");
            $Data[50] = array(1000=>"10000");
         break;
      }

      echo "<option value=''></option>";
      foreach($Data[$_GET['ajax']] as $K => $V)
      {
         echo "<option value='$K'>$V</option>\n";
      }
      mysql_close($dbh);
      exit; //we're finished so exit..
   }
   $Data = array(1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three");
   $List1 = "<option value=''></option>";
   foreach($Data as $K => $V)
   {
      $List1 .= "<option value='$K'>$V</option>\n";
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Simple Dymanic Drop Down</title>
<script language="javascript">
   function ajaxFunction(ID, Param)
   {
      //link to the PHP file your getting the data from
      //var loaderphp = "register.php";
      //i have link to this file
      var loaderphp = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>";

      //we don't need to change anymore of this script
      var xmlHttp;
      try
       {
         // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }catch(e){
         // Internet Explorer
         try
         {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(e){
            try
            {
               xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
               alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
               return false;
            }
         }
      }

      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
           {
              //the line below reset the third list box incase list 1 is changed
              document.getElementById('LBox3').innerHTML = "<option value=''></option>";

              //THIS SET THE DAT FROM THE PHP TO THE HTML
            document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
           }
      }
       xmlHttp.open("GET", loaderphp+"?ID="+ID+"&ajax="+Param,true);
       xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- OK a basic form-->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" target="_self">
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--
      OK here we call the ajaxFuntion LBox2 refers to where the returned date will go
      and the this.value will be the value of the select option
      -->
      <select name="list1" id="LBox1" onchange="ajaxFunction('LBox2', this.value);">
      <?php 
         echo $List1;
      ?>
      </select>
   </td>
    <td>
      <select name="list2" id="LBox2" onchange="ajaxFunction('LBox3', this.value);">
         <option value=''></option>
            <!-- OK the ID of this list box is LBox2 as refered to above -->
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <select name="list3" id="LBox3">
         <option value=''></option>
            <!-- OK the ID of this list box is LBox3 Same as above -->
      </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't started learning JavaScript, and i need this for a project. I'll appreciate it if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is too vague. The sample code posted has very little to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't understand your question vary well but i'll try to help you in general. in the html be sure that you use the method="get" for the form and in this way the variables are passed to the php in the url. (in other cases POST needed but for now you are ok even with get). all the input's values with the NAME attribute set are passed into the url. ex:

```
<form action='phpscript.php' method='get' >
<input type='text' name='just_a_test' value='somevalue' />
<input type='submit' value='submit_form' name='submit' />
</form>
```

the url after submiting will be : 
    http://mypage.com/phpscript.php?just_a_test=somevalue&submit=submit_form

in the other side the php script that will use the data from the form will be

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['submit']) ) { 

                              if (isset($_GET['just_a_test']) )
                                  {
                                  $variable1 = $_GET['just_a_test'];
                                  //do something with variable 1 and output results
                                  //based on the value of this variable. 
                                  }
                             } 

?>

you can do the same thing for ass many variables as you want . i hope this was a help to you because i cant undestand your question better than this .
```

Answer (score 1):

If the form is supposed to be sent during a redirect, you are not using AJAX. In this case the solution is simple:

```
<form name="myForm" action="test.php" method="GET">
    <select name="idneeded">
        <option value="40">MadTechie</option>
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Things like these are explained in every HTML tutorial. This is a good starting point: [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned if the value of the variable is available on client or server?

**Variable on Client:**
  Basically, you will have to handle the onSubmit event of the form. Here you can append the value of the variable to the action.

**Variable on Server:**
  Here you would change the action when you are rendering the HTML.

Comment: thanks, I just learned another tip form your post. my variable is available on the sever. and @Albi Patozi just answered my question and solved my problem. Thanks again for your explanation.